# How to select color range in CorelDraw?

Tags: corel-draw

How to select color range in CorelDraw?

I want to select a specific colored object and delete it.

I don't need to replace the color, just specify the color I need, highlight it and delete it.

Is there any option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to select it is on the same place as the option to replace it.

Go to Find and replace. (I agree, It should read search or replace)

Menu > Edit > Find and Replace.

- Select search.
- Choose Fill as the search method.
- Choose the specific color, you can use the eyedropper.

Finish that search, and the floating bar has a three buttons.

- Search all and all objects with that color will be selected at once, you can delete all pressing "Del" key.
- Search next will go arround the objects with that color untill you find the one you need.
  [image]

Comment: there is no such menu search and replace in coreldraw

Comment: ... There is...

Comment: Thanks u have said search and replace it is find and replace.

Comment: I was "lost in translation". My bad.